# Logging Remote Python Script Execution on 100s of Machines and Sending Back Results to Common Log Document

Tags: python, google-sheets, logging, cloud

I have taught myself python for work (its a work in progress) and my most recent script is wrapped into an executable. Long story short, I will be running it on hundreds of PCs at different locations across the country. It moves some files around, edits info in them, checks the PCs license, etc. and prints out statements at each step of the way.

These PCs are all identical images of one another (minus a few key bits of data) but are all on their own unique networks. **I am looking for a way to have my python script send (log) the print statements back to a common document.** This would allow me to comb through said document and identify which PCs did not execute all the tasks I am working to complete successfully.

Thus far I have thought about using a google sheet and googles apis (with gsread or other libraries) to simply send back the bits of info I want and document that as a new line in the common spreadsheet. **But it has me wondering:** is there is as a more elegant, python-like, solution to this problem that I have not thought about. Again, I am new to this and doing my best to learn/explain my problem so all suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

***TLDR: Hundreds of near-identical pcs on unique networks need to run the same script. I would like to log their execution in a common document so that I can look through and see which computers I need to take a closer look at.***

```py
import csv
import os

# define func to find serial number and set to var serial
def get_sn():
    command = "wmic bios get serialnumber"
    return os.popen(command).read().replace("\n","").replace("  ","").replace(" ","").replace("SerialNumber","")
serial = get_sn()
# bring csv data into python dict
with open("marine_data.csv", mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(infile)
    data = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}

# set woo license equal to value pair for serial key and send success message
if data.get(serial) is not None:
    license = data[serial]
    print("SUCCESS: Match Found For Serial " + serial)
# if key does not exist set woo license equal to generic val and send failure message
else:
    license = "generic-T1"
    print("FAILURE: No Match Found For Serial " + serial)
infile.close()

# define vars for use in editing set file
user_profile = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
output = os.path.join(user_profile, 'Documents', 'some-program', 'global.set')
file_in = open("global.set", "rt")
file_out = open(output, "wt")
# replace generic license id
for line in file_in:
    file_out.write(line.replace('generic-T1', license))
file_in.close()
file_out.close()
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are running if its not too long?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a TCP or HTTP server which listens for logging events on a particular port, on a server you control, and have the code on the various PCs connect to it over the network and send their logging events to it, which it then stores to a common place. See [SocketHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#sockethandler) or [HTTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler) for the client end and [this cookbook recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) for example server-side code using TCP/IP.